# Función en Python indicando si una palabra que recibe como parámetro posee todas las vocales del alfabeto y su orden

Tags: python

he estado intentando realizar una programa el cual me permita ingresar una palabra por ejemplo "albericoque", la cual contiene todas las vocales de manera ordenada. Este programa al ingresar el texto debe clasificar primeramente si contiene todas las vocales, sino es asi se debe cerrar, en el caso contrario debe clasificar si la palabra esta ordenada de manera acendente, decendente o de manera desordenada alfabeticamente.

Se debe pasar por alto el case sensitive, encontrar por igual la “A”, como la “a”
minúscula.
Además, deberá ser capaz de determinar el orden de las vocales sin repetir por
ejemplo “A-E-I-O-U” como ascendente (in order), “U-O-I-E” descendente (in
decent order), además las no ordenadas osea desordenadas (unordered).
Asi mismo si una palabra no contiene todas las vocales el programa debe cerrarse(does not apply).
Deberá retornar una cadena con el siguiente formato:
all vowels (yes/no) – (does not apply, in order, in decent order, unordered).

En base a lo que se solicito, he intentado primeramente saber si una palabra esta correctamente ordenada, la cual si es asi me devuelve un booleano con true, de lo contrario que me devuelva un false. Sin embargo no lo he conseguido relizar correctamente, ademas no he encontrado alguna funcion que me permita coneguir el orden de una palabra alfabeticamente.

```
entrada = input ("Ingrese una palabra ")
entradaMinuscula = entrada.lower()
#Proceso
i = 0
salida = True;
while i+1 < len (entradaMinuscula):
    if entradaMinuscula[i] < entradaMinuscula[i+1]:
        salida = True
    else:
        salida = False
        break
    i += 1
#Salida
if salida == True:
    print ("Es una palabra alfabética correctamente")
else:
    print ("No es una palabra alfabética correctamente")
```

Agradeceria algun tipo de consejo o ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas de un bucle `while` para esto, sí lo puedes hacer, pero yo usaría un `for` en su lugar, incluso una expresión generadora pero esto implicar volver a recorrer la cadena una vez más (a menos que uses algún módulo de `itertools` o hagas algunas cosas raras).

```py
vocales = "aeiou"

def analizar(palabra: str) -> str:
    vocales_palabra = ''
    for letra in palabra.lower():
        if letra in vocales and not letra in vocales_palabra: 
            vocales_palabra+= letra

    if len(vocales_palabra) != 5: 
        return "No contiene todas las vocales"
    
    if vocales_palabra == vocales: 
        return "Ordenado de forma ascendente alfabeticamente"
    elif vocales_palabra == vocales[::-1]: 
        return "Ordenado de forma descendente alfabeticamente"
    else: return "Desordenado"
```

La función es bastante sencilla, primero recorremos cada letra de la palabra, luego verificamos que la letra esté dentro de las vocales (variable `vocales` definida antes de la función, es una variable global) y a su vez verificamos que esta no esté dentro de `vocales_palabra` que es la variable que almacena las vocales que va apareciendo en la palabra. Si pasa las validaciones entonces se agrega a `vocales_palabra`.

Como siguiente parte del código tenemos unos bloque `if/else/elif` que se encargarán de validar si la palabra tiene todas las vocales, si está ordenado ascendente o descendentemente o si está desordenado.

El primer `if` comprueba el largo de la variable `vocales_palabra` esta debe ser de 5 (ya que hay 5 vocales), si es distinto de 5 significa que no tiene todas las vocales. El segundo `if` verifica que esté ordenado de forma ascendente, para ello lo comparamos con la variable `vocales` (la variable global que contiene las vocales de forma ascendente) y para saber si está de forma descendente solo tenemos que invertir la variable `vocales`, eso se logra con la expresión `vocales[::-1]`. Si ninguna de esas condiciones se cumplió entonces significa que está desordenado.

Ahora solo falta probarlo:

```py
palabra = "albericoque"
resultado = analizar(palabra)
print(resultado)

# salida:
# Ordenado de forma ascendente alfabeticamente
```

Si tienes alguna duda acerca del código puedes hacérmela saber en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Demasiado claro, muchas gracias por la explicacion ;)